# How can I access Ref when extending another widget

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am trying to make a custom form field in Flutter for selecting one of many `Location`s retrieved from a backend API.  I am using riverpod to store these `Location` objects across the application.  Since I can't extend `ConsumerState`, I'm not sure how to go about getting the WidgetRef in order to access the list of `Location`s.

```
class LocationField extends FormField<Location> {
  LocationField({
    super.key,
  }) : super(
          builder: (context) {
            throw UnimplementedError();
          },
        );

  @override
  FormFieldState<Location> createState() => _LocationFieldState();
}

class _LocationFieldState extends FormFieldState<Location> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO : How do I access ref here?
    final locationsData = ref.read(locationsProvider);
    final List<String> options = locationsData.value?.map((location) => location.name) ?? [];

    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a workable context (edit: are in a widget's build method), you can always inject a [Consumer](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/latest/flutter_riverpod/Consumer-class.html) widget, which means you'll get a new local context *and* a new local `ref`.